# Do airlines block out a large section of seats online?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, seating

A family friend tried to book a last minute holiday for their family but when they tried to book online they couldn't get seats together. When he rang the airline up they had no problem putting them together.

Do a lot of airlines make it look as if they have few remaining seats left and what are the advantages of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The airline can move passengers around, even if they have chosen seats (you'll always see the disclaimer when you choose a seat online) - whereas the online booking system won't necessarily know if it can do this.

Also, the airline may have more up to date knowledge of cancellations at that stage.

So the problem isn't the airline making it look like there are few remaining seats, but that the system won't let you move other passengers in order to fit a group in at short notice.

When I make late bookings with the family, I just plan for the fact that we may all have to sit in different areas on the plane. Sometimes it can be sorted, but certainly not every time. That's the hazard of late booking.